# How do I display E384B1, etc. in Korean Hangul?

Tags: java, unicode, display

I have a simple ReadWriteUnicode class that displays unicode values in a Frame using drawString.  I test it using \u65e5\u672 and MONOSPACED Font and get Chinese.  When I pass it \ue384b1\ue384b2 etc. and Font name Hangul, I get []b1[]b2, where the [] is a square box.

How do I get the three byte codes to display Hangul Korean?

```
public class ReadWriteUnicodeExample {

    static void writeOutput(String str) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
            out.write(str);
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static String readInput() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
            Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
                buffer.append((char)ch);
            }
            in.close();
            return buffer.toString();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jaString = new String("\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u6587\u5b57\u5217");
        writeOutput(jaString); 
        String inputString = readInput();
        String displayString = jaString + " " + inputString;
        new ShowString(displayString, "Conversion Demo", "MONOSPACED");
        String koreanStr = new String ("\ue384b1\ue384b2\ue384b4\ue384b7\ue384b8\ue384b9");
        writeOutput(koreanStr); 
        inputString = readInput();
        displayString = koreanStr + " " + inputString;
        new ShowString(displayString, "Conversion Demo", "Hangul");
    }
}

class ShowString extends Frame {

    FontMetrics fontM;
    String outString;

    ShowString (String target, String title, String fontName) {

        setTitle(title);
        outString = target;

        Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 36);
        fontM = getFontMetrics(font);
        setFont(font);

        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < outString.length(); i++) {
           size += fontM.charWidth(outString.charAt(i));
        }
        size += 24;

        setSize(size, fontM.getHeight() + 60);
        setLocation(getSize().width/2, getSize().height/2);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int x = insets.left; 
        int y = insets.top;
        g.drawString(outString, x + 6, y + fontM.getAscent() + 14);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like your characters are actually hangul. See hangul block here http://www.programminginkorean.com/programming/hangul-in-unicode/

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I'm using information from http://memory.loc.gov/diglib/codetables/9.3.html which is used by the Library of Congress.  They give those values in the UTF8 column.  How do I go from those to the ones you give in the reference above?

Comment: But characters of the format `\uxxxx` aren't UTF-8. They're unicode escapes.

Comment: So UTF8 != Unicode. There is an important difference in that UTF8 is an encoding. the `\uxxxx` just needs to be the unicode codepoint for your character

Comment: So what are those UTF8 items in the Library of Congress tables?  If I want to display Hangul character which LoC says is UTF8 e384b9, what do I do?

Comment: @JohnWooten It means that if that particular character were to be written somewhere (file, network) as bytes, encoded in `UTF-8`, it would consist of those bytes. The `\uxxxx` is an abstract representation of the character.

Comment: So, you are saying that if I write out \u3139 to a UTF8 stream, it will be written as bytes 'e384b9' in the stream.  When I read in those bytes from a UTF8 stream, how do I convert them into \u3139 for display, or is that done automagically?

Comment: Thanks!  I wrote a small program to do a hex dump of my output file and found it was exactly as you said.  When it is read back in, it becomes the proper display codes again.

Comment: I did notice that it makes no difference what "Font" I tell it to use for displaying the unicode characters in a Frame, the result is the same, e.g.:
new ShowString(displayString, "Korean Hangul", "Hangul"); and
new ShowString(displayString, "Korean Hangul", "MONOSPACED"); both display exactly the same thing for displayString = new String ("\u3131\u3139\u3142\u3148\u314a\u314e\u65e5");  In ShowString above, the Font name is used to set the Font, etc.  So is it even necessary to worry about the Font except for the Font metrics?